# color in ggplot2 legend not matching figure

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a problem getting the legend in ggplot2 to correspond to the color in the figure. And I have extra variables in the legend. I have read many posts on similar issues but unfortunately I have not been able to apply those to this situation - successfully at least. I tried using "fill" and "scale_fill_manual()", "theme()" and several others, but to no avail yet. Hopefully I am just missing something simple here, I appreciate any suggestions!

I am making a map and my code right now is:

```
ggplot()+ geom_map(data=world, map=world,aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),color="white", fill="#7f7f7f", size=0.05)+
   geom_point(aes(x=long.a,y=lat.a, size=var.p, color="red", alpha=0.5))
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Move the color and alpha outside of the `aes()` since they are not mapped to your data: `geom_point(aes(x=long.a,y=lat.a, size=var.p), color="red", alpha=0.5)`

Comment: Yep you got it! I swear I tried that at one point because I moved them inside aes(), but I don't know where I had them, ha. Thank you very much!